# How to create a Database Role to Allow Users to alter only a particular stored procedure in a db in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000, database-administration

There is no built in database role that allows this kind of access. The `db_datareader`  wouldn’t allow a user to see stored procedures or functions at all. The `ddladmin` database role would provide access to see the objects, but also to change them as well, which is not the intent here. To accomplish the desired result of this type of request requires that a new database role be created?

How to give full access on a particular stored procedure in SQL Server 2000? Example I have a stored procedure called `sp_prg1` in database `db1`. I need to give full access only on `sp_prg1` (which include altering the stored procedure) to a user.

how to give only alter permissions to only one  stored procedure
this GRANT alter on [db].[dbo].[storedprocedure1] TO SingleObjectRole is not working

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: Ok thanks for the information.Please can you sugest the answer to main question

Comment: USE db
EXEC sp_addrole 'SingleObjectRole'

GRANT alter  on   [db].[dbo].[storedprocedure1] TO SingleObjectRole

The grant command seems to have problem